# Socket.io sharing socket data between namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to know how to share data being set in a socket in one namespace and access it on another namespace?

I'm fully aware that i can attach data to the socket object itself.Problem arise when i attach the data on one namespace and try to access it on another namespace.

Below demonstrate the problem

```
var io = require( 'socket.io' );

module.exports.init = function( server ) {

    io = io.listen( server );

    io.of( '/chatSystem' ).on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
        /*handling set nickname event*/
        socket.on( 'set.name', function( data ) {
            /*attach nickname key to this socket*/
            socket.nickname = data.name;
            socket.broadcast.emit( 'user.entered', data );
        });
    });

    io.of( '/chatUser').on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
        /*handling client event socket.send*/
        socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
            data = JSON.parse( data );
            data.nickname = socket.nickname; // <--- this is undefined

            /*send to all connected client( broadcast will not send message to socket that created the message)*/
            socket.broadcast.send( JSON.stringify( data ) );
            data.type = 'myMessage';

            /*manually send back the message to the socket that created the message*/
            socket.send( JSON.stringify( data) );
        });
    });
};
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Name set in one name namespace is found undefined when tried to fetch in another namespace.
If all the messages are sent using only one socket `io.on('connection', function() {.....})` this works fine. But not with two different namespaces.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and would like to have an answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit late but i just stumbled on a simpler solution and thought i would share for future investigators.

with socket > 1.0, you can store shared data in the socket's client object. It seems to still be shared among sockets

to use your example above

```
    /* attach nickname key to this socket */
    socket.client.nickname = data.name;
    /* In typescript with @types/socket.io */
    socket.client["nickname"] = data.name;
```

and for retrieval

```
    data.nickname = socket.client.nickname;
    /* In typescript with @types/socket.io */
    data.name = socket.client["nickname"];
```

Hope this helps someone out. I have been trying to find a solution all week and stumbled on this thread. An hour later, I found this alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATING MY ANSWER FOR A MORE GENERIC AND "SAFER" SOLUTION

It turns out that we *could* share data across namespaces, but we have to do that by referring the socket instance from once namespace to another.

Suppose there are two namespaces, namely, **namespace_A** and **namespace_B**.

To get the corresponding **socket** object on **namepsace_A** from within **namespace_B**, we fetch it by using the current **socket** object's ID (as it will be similar) from the **connected** object in the **namespace_A** namespace object.

Though this is still kind of an workaround, but this is by far the best and safest way I have been able to share session data among namespaces.

We'll use the socket.id to refer to the required sockets.
The IDs look something like this: `/namespace#vCpuzzUi4RI1DHqfAAAH`.
Each socket instance within the namespaces have the IDs similar except for the **namespace** portion, i. e., for namespace_A, the ID would be something like `/namespace_A#vCpuzzUi4RI1DHqfAAAH` and for namespace_B it would be `/namespace_B#vCpuzzUi4RI1DHqfAAAH`. Therefore we could refer one socket instance from one namespace in another if we could generate a socket ID similar to the present socket and use it.

What we need to do is first declare a variable at the beginning like:

```
var self = this;
```

This is used to hold a reference to the present object.
Next within one namespace, suppose **namespace_A**, we need data from socket instance of **namespace_B** by writing this code in A:

```
ns_b_socket = self.namespace_B.connected['/namespace_B#' + buildSocketID(socket.id)];
```

We refer to the namespace_B of the present instance using `self.namespace_B` and then call **connected** over it.

> Namespace#connected:Object
>
> Hash of Socket objects that are connected to this namespace indexed by
>   id.

I use a custom function to generate the ID.

```
function buildSocketID(iden) {
    return iden.split('#')[1];  
}
```

Now, if you call `ns_b_socket.username` from `namespace_A`, you'd get the value set for `socket.username` from **namespace_B**.

**NOTE:** This works for version 1.0.x and above. For version below this, refer [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1618).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I thought of a workround. watch

```
var io = require( 'socket.io' );
```

module.exports.init = function( server ) {

```
 /**
     * Hi This is where things, get tricky now.
     * statement of Problem: Am trying to send message between two namespaces.
     * first made individual namespace socket global,
     * And create a function that will utilized these global sockets as their second arguments
     * and make calls to them
     */

io = io.listen( server );
var chatSystemPresentSocket; // making it Global
var chatUserPresentSocket;  //making it Global

io.of( '/chatSystem' ).on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    /*handling set nickname event*/
    socket.on( 'set.name', function( data ) {
        /*attach nickname key to this socket*/
        //socket Global for the moment.
        chatSystemPresentSocket = socket;

        sendtochatSystem(data) // function calls
        socket.nickname = data.name;
        socket.broadcast.emit( 'user.entered', data );
    });
});

io.of( '/chatUser').on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    /*handling client event socket.send*/
    socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        /* make socket global for the moment.*/
        chatUserPresentSocket = socket;
        sendtochatSystem(data);
        data = JSON.parse( data );
        data.nickname = socket.nickname; // <--- this is undefined

        /*send to all connected client( broadcast will not send message to socket that created the message)*/
        socket.broadcast.send( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        data.type = 'myMessage';

        /*manually send back the message to the socket that created the message*/
        socket.send( JSON.stringify( data) );
    });
});

//Make a function to use one of the global sockets of one of the namespaces
function sendToChatUser(data, chatUserPresentSocket){
chatUserPresentSocket.emit('your event', data)
}

function sendToChatSystem(data, chatSystemPresentSocket){
chatSystemPresentSocket.emit('your event', data)
}
```

};

Test it, if it doesnt fit in you know, where to edit in my code